# Is it possible to update an element in HTML through a DynamoDB Lambda trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to I have a Lambda function (index.js) that is triggered by DynamoDB and gets an item from the table and passes that data to an index.html in the same folder, updating its content. is it possible to have that index.html file be hosted at the same time as being accessible by this lambda?

My goal is to trigger a Lambda each time a new entry is made into my DynamoDB table. I want the Lambda to simply update an element in an HTML file (eg, a header) based on data I get from a read operation on the DynamoDB table.

I plan to host the HTML file on AWS, via S3 or AWS Amplify. I am not too fussed which option I use. I just want the lambda to automatically change an element in that hosted HTML file when triggered by the DynamoDB table.

I have researched the documentation and on here, but can't find a solution for this. Many mention using REST API etc, but those same suggestions are for building WebApps with way more detail and functionality than what I want. Is this possible without using Amazon API Gateway etc. Can I not just access the hosted HTML file from within the Lambda?

Comment: Yes, use DynamoDB Streams. Each DynamoDB update can trigger a Lambda function and that Lambda function can do whatever it likes (including updating the content of an HTML file hosted in S3). You should watch out  for web page caching, of course, to ensure that your clients get the latest HTML file.

Comment: Great thanks. I will try that then. Would it be directly going into the hosted HTML file on S3? Is this possible? E.g. changing a header. Or would I have to just reupload the entire HTML file with the changes?

Comment: You can't modify files in S3. You would upload a new version.